Can't connect to a Oracle SQL local database (ORA-50000 timeout error)
I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to connect to a local Oracle SQL database.
With this source:
OracleConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new();
//fake password and username, but I double checked they're correct.
connStr.UserID = "admin"; //user was created with sqlplus from a command prompt
connStr.Password = "1234";
connStr.DataSource = "localhost:1521/xe";

_conn = new OracleConnection(connStr.ConnectionString);
_conn.Open(); // <- exception here after tens of seconds

I get a Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-50000: Connection request timed out' exception in the Open call.
I've also tried connecting to my university's iSQLPlus database, but I get the same error.
On my local database, connecting using Oracle SQL Developer works with no issues.

I expected the connection to obviously succeed, but I get the timeout error.

Are you using exactly the same data source URL in Oracle SQL Developer?

They seem to be the same, I've also added a picture from SQL Dev.

You should use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core for .NET (versions 5, 6, 7, 8), and for .NET Framework (version 4.8), you can utilize the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library.
This is primarily a .NET library compatibility issue.
